# Phonegap has recently stopped working?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios9, download

I haven't used it in a while until now but I cannot get it to work anymore even with a new, generated and unchanged, project. It worked perfectly fine before. It's been updated and the mobile app has been updated.. I've tried the desktop and CLI version.

Details:
Using Windows 10. Desktop App or CLI Phonegap.
Using iPhone iOS 9.0.2 mobile Phonegap app.
Using the basic, generated Phonegap Hello World.

What happens:
1. I serve the application.
 
2. I open the mobile app and enter credentials.
3. It sits on "Downloading" indefinitely

Note: If I open the URL in a browser on the serving machine it WILL open. If I open it on any other machine it will not.. This confuses me because they're on the same WiFi network so that has nothing to do with it. I even tried turning off my firewall in case the port was being blocked or something. I've tried 3000 and 8080.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I've uninstalled, re-reinstalled, used different versions, etc...

**EDIT:** I've found a solution, kind of.. If I use the --localtunnel flag it will work. I'm not sure why given that they ARE on the same network. Of course this also means that every single time I serve it is a different address which is quite a hassle. But at least I can test now.

Comment: there is a 3rd party app for iPhones called: `cordova browser`, have you tried to see if it work fine on it ?

Comment: Afraid that doesn't make a difference /: But I'm about to edit an update. Found a solution, kind of..